# How to change circle to rectangle when mouse hovers on the heat map charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GreatFusion/tb5y1ztg/
when mouse hovers on the block it shows a big circle extends out of the block. How to make the circle smaller or some other methods to reshape the circle? Absolutely,If I set the `plotOptions.series.states.hover.enabled` to false can hide the circle,but in this case, I cannot set the`borderWidth`,`color`.e.g. 
Seems there is no `marker` attribute in heat map.
Thank you!

Comment: what circle? i don't see any circle. http://jsfiddle.net/tb5y1ztg/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if you set the `chat.width:300`,you will find the circle.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set:

```
hover:{
   enabled:false,
   borderColor:'#FF0000'
}
```

and that circle will disappear (for all widths and heights). Idk what bordercolor you're talking about but the border color of the hover detail window still shows.

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/tb5y1ztg/3/)**

Comment: If the set `hover.enabled:false`,`hover.borderColor:'#FF0000'` will not work. And I cannot see the red border when mouse on a block in your demo. Thank you.

Comment: i can see the border... http://tinypic.com/r/n4bf5d/8  it will be of the same color as tile whether hover enabled or disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you mean is the border color of tooltip. I want to set border color on the block itself.

Comment: You can compare these two cases:`hover:{enabled:false,borderColor:'#FF0000'}` and `hover:{enabled:true,borderColor:'#FF0000'}`. You will find the red border in the second case.

Comment: i really don't see the difference.. http://jsfiddle.net/tb5y1ztg/3/  make a case where there is border

Comment: Ok,You can compare these two cases:`hover:{enabled:false,borderColor:'#00FF00'}` and `hover:{enabled:true,borderColor:'#00FF00'}`. When mouse hovers on the tile,you will see the green border.You cannot miss it.

Answer (score 0):

You can control it by hover staates or [halo](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.states.hover.halo) options.